# How to override setStackTrace(),printStackTrace() to show the message of Exception in desire format

Tags: java, exception

I want I need to create exception Framework which will print the exception In the way i want to be printed.

For that i guess i need to override getLocalisedMessage(),getCause(); setStackTrace(),printStackTrace().

Anybody please guide me how to do that(Any code)

Comment: And what language are you talking about sir ?

Comment: I've added the java tag, since all those methods are in the java Exception class.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is Java you are asking about:

```
public class MyException extends Exception {

    @Override
    public String getLocalizedMessage() {
        // your code
    }

    // same for the rest you want to override
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is Throwable#getStackTrace what you're looking for?  this returns the raw stack as an array.  you can then iterate and pretty-print however you want.

Comment: Actually I wanted Something to change in throwable object so that when exception is printed in console ; it should be in user modified way. Not like above answer specied. when I mention the above method needs to be overriden ;Then definitely i know the signature